# JNI GetFieldID called with pending exception 'java.lang.NoSuchFieldError'

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I can't figure out why do I always get this error

> JNI GetFieldID called with pending exception 'java.lang.NoSuchFieldError'
>   .

trying to call `GetFieldID()` method.

Here is my `MainActivity` with `mFd` reference and from which the native method gets called:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ...
    private FileDescriptor mFd;
}
```

Snippet of code bellow shows the process of creating a file descriptor:

```
JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL Java_ua_taras_appc_MainActivity_configure (...)
{
 /* Create a corresponding file descriptor */
    {
        jclass cFileDescriptor = (*env)->FindClass(env, "java/io/FileDescriptor");
        jmethodID iFileDescriptor = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, cFileDescriptor, "<init>", "()V");
        jfieldID descriptorID = (*env)->GetFieldID(env, cFileDescriptor, "descriptor", "I");
        mFileDescriptor = (*env)->NewObject(env, cFileDescriptor, iFileDescriptor);
        (*env)->SetIntField(env, mFileDescriptor, descriptorID, (jint)fd);
    }
    return mFileDescriptor;
}
```

And here where I fetch `int` value of file descriptor:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_ua_taras_appc_MainActivity_readuart (...)
{
    jclass MainActivityClass = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, thiz);
    jclass FileDescriptorClass = (*env)->FindClass(env, "java/io/FileDescriptor");

    jfieldID mFdID = (*env)->GetFieldID(env, MainActivityClass, "mFd", "Ljava/io/FileDescriptor;");
    jfieldID descriptorID = (*env)->GetFieldID(env, FileDescriptorClass, "descriptor", "I");

    jobject mFd = (*env)->GetObjectField(env, thiz, mFdID);
    jint descriptor = (*env)->GetIntField(env, mFd, descriptorID);
}
```

Comment: You can do all this with Reflection. No need for the riskier JNI option.

Answer (score 2):

So there was no such field as a result of the prior

```
jfieldID mFdID = (*env)->GetFieldID(env, MainActivityClass, "mFd", "Ljava/io/FileDescriptor;");
```

this being the only place where you called `GetFieldID()` twice in a row, 
and you failed to check for an error. You must error-check *all* JNI API calls.